# Someone’s home—his, hers, mine?

Tags: possessives

When I say “we’re staying at his/hers”, it means that we’re staying at his or her home.
Can I say “we’re staying at mine” which I refer to my home?

Comment: The common way to say this is "we're staying at my place".

Comment: Where can you say "I'm staying at his" instead of _I'm staying with him/at his place_? This must be a local expression somewhere.

Comment: I would only say "We're staying at his/hers" if someone had just asked "Whose place are you staying at?"  It doesn't make sense without something to give it context.

Comment: Thinking about it, I *might* say "We're staying at mine" in very casual speech, but I cannot justify its use in good written English.

Comment: @randomhead - this usage - 'mine' meaning 'my place', 'my home', 'my gaff' etc is _very very_ common in UK relaxed speech, especially among younger folk (say under 40). Also yours, his, hers, etc. In fact [it seems to be a meme](https://memes.com/m/so-we-meet-for-pre-drinks-at-mine-head-over-to-3-Wxq0o_rRk): '“So we meet for pre-drinks at mine, head over to Acme, then drinks at the Spaniard and maybe if we are feeling wiiiiild head over to Brooklyn?”' - seems they say it in the US too.

Comment: ... Yes, it seems to be a rarity, where the UK is outpacing the US in adopting new forms of casual speech.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I've never heard it in the US.  I don't make claims to be some kind of ultimate authority on recent slang and usage, of course! - but I've never run into it here.  I did find [one very formal discussion of the construction](http://itre.cis.upenn.edu/~myl/languagelog/archives/003811.html), and [one informal mention of it as a British thing that tripped up an American](https://www.hercampus.com/school/ufl/british-phrases-deciphered-guide-surviving-london-lingo).

Comment: In fact it's 'drinks at mine' which is a meme.

Comment: I think this usage (without explicit noun ***place, house, flat*** or whatever) doesn't work very well with ***any*** pronouns. But that's not to say it doesn't work ***at all***. Sometimes it's "okay" [-*ish!*] to say things like *They're staying at mine tomorrow*.

Comment: Yes. It's not the most common way, but it is natural.

Answer (score 2):

In American English, it is most commonly "my place."

In British English, it is often "mine."

There is some regional variation on that as well.